# Consider the IVP $ x'=h(t)g(x),\quad x(t_0)=x_0$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Consider the IVP
>   $$
> x'=h(t)g(x),\quad x(t_0)=x_0,
> $$
>   where $$h\in C([a,\,\infty),\,[0,\,\infty)),\,g\in C([0,\,\infty),\,(0,\,\infty)),\;t_0\in[a,\,\infty),~~\text{and}~~x_0\in[0,\,\infty)~.$$ Moreover, $$\int_{x_0}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{g(x)}=\infty~.$$ Show that every solution of the IVP exists on $~[t_0,\infty)$.

I think it should be proved by Gronwall inequality. But I don't know how to apply it and how to use the condition $$\int_{x_0}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{g(x)}=\infty~.$$

Comment: What do you know about the method of separation of variables, and about the invertibility of monotonous functions?